# Can't make a child process open (create) a file with the required name

Tags: c, io, pipe, parent-child

The program should do the following:

1. Read two file names from the terminal.
2. Send each file name from the parent to the corresponding child (first entry for child 1, second for child 2).
3. Read an arbitrary amount of strings from the terminal and send them to one of child processes (if the string is more than 10 chars, then to child 2, else to child 1) for them to write those strings in the file you assigned in the beginning.

```
const int BUFF = 1024;

int main()
{
    int id1, id2, pipe_1[2], pipe_2[2];

    if (pipe(pipe_1) == -1){ perror("pipe1"); return -1;}
    if (pipe(pipe_2) == -1){ perror("pipe2"); return -1;}

    (id1 = fork()) && (id2 = fork());
    
    if (id1 == -1){
        perror("child1");
        return -1;
    }
    if (id2 == -1){
        perror("child2");
        return -1;
    }

    if (id1 == 0){
        //child 1
        int str_len, file_name_len, fd_file;

        read(pipe_1[0], &file_name_len, sizeof(size_t));
        char file_name[file_name_len];
        read(pipe_1[0], file_name, file_name_len);

        read(pipe_1[0], &str_len, sizeof(int));
        char str[str_len];
        read(pipe_1[0], str, str_len);

        close(pipe_1[0]); close(pipe_1[1]);

        fd_file = open(file_name, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_APPEND, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);

        write(fd_file, str, str_len);
        close(fd_file);

    } else if (id2 == 0){
        //child 2
        int str_len, file_name_len, fd_file;

        read(pipe_2[0], &file_name_len, sizeof(size_t));
        char file_name[file_name_len];
        read(pipe_2[0], file_name, file_name_len);

        read(pipe_2[0], &str_len, sizeof(int));
        char str[str_len];
        read(pipe_2[0], str, str_len);

        close(pipe_2[0]); close(pipe_2[1]);

        fd_file = open(file_name, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_APPEND, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);

        write(fd_file, str, str_len);
        close(fd_file);

    } else {
        //parent
        char str[BUFF];

        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
            char file_name[BUFF];
            read(STDIN_FILENO, file_name, BUFF);
            size_t file_len = strlen(file_name);
            if (i == 0){
                write(pipe_1[1], &file_len, sizeof(size_t));
                write(pipe_1[1], file_name, file_len);
            } else {
                write(pipe_2[1], &file_len, sizeof(size_t));
                write(pipe_2[1], file_name, file_len);
            }
        }

        int k = 0, str_len = 0;
        while(1){
            read(STDIN_FILENO, str, BUFF);
            if (str[0] == '\n'){
                break;
            }
            
            while(str[k] != '\n'){
                k++;str_len++;
            }

            if (str_len > 10){
                // to child 2
                write(pipe_1[1], &str_len, sizeof(int));
                write(pipe_1[1], str, str_len);
            } else {
                //to child 1
                write(pipe_2[1], &str_len, sizeof(int));
                write(pipe_2[1], str, str_len);
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason I keep getting it to create the messed up version of the first file ('aaa.txt'$'\n''�^Ǡ�'$'\177' instead of aaa.txt). The second file isn't created at all.

How can I make it work properly?

Comment: Your file_len and file_name are not correctly sending the string NUL terminator. All C strings need to have that NUL terminator otherwise it is not a valid string. Send and read one extra character.

Comment: What tells you that a C string has reached its end?

Comment: @AndrewHenle when the line ends. '/n' in the end of a string.

Comment: Umm, no.  Not at all.  What have you been told about the definition of a string in C? Go back to that.  You need to get this right - it is absolutely fundamental to using strings in C.  How does your **computer** know where the string ends?

Comment: @AndrewHenle okay. I understood I need to add '/0' to the end of each string.

Comment: @kaylum it still creates odd files like '1.txt'$'\n' when I added 
```file_name[file_len] = '\0';
file_len += 1;``` 
to the code.

Comment: Did you increase the array by one? Needs to be: `char file_name[file_name_len+1];`. Or the sending side needs to send the size increased by 1 and send the NUL.